# Road Restrictions with osm2po

Tags: pgrouting, osm2po

I'm currently using osm2po version 5.5.5 to import data from OpenStreetMap (OSM) into a SQL graph file. My primary concern is to include restrictions on the roads during the import process. To achieve this, I set the parameter "rtr.support.restrictions" to "true."

After enabling this setting, I noticed that some restrictions, such as "no U-turn" on certain roads, were missing from the generated graph. My initial assumption was that the parameter "rtr.support.route.types" was responsible for this issue. To investigate further, I modified the original value of "rtr.support.route.types" from "#rtr.support.route.types = bus, bicycle" to "rtr.support.route.types = road, bus, bicycle" hoping it would resolve the problem.

However, despite making this configuration change, the result remained the same, and I am still encountering the missing restrictions. I would appreciate any guidance on the correct configuration settings for "osm2po.config" to ensure that all restrictions are correctly included during the import process.

Comment: What restrictions on the roads are you trying to add? Exclude certain tags in OSM like highway=service?